# Debug Sencha App in Mobile Browser

Tags: android, mobile, extjs

Good Day!
I am a newbie to the mobile tech. I have a question hope you can give me some tips or help.
My problem right now is i have a sencha app. I try deploy it using android eclipse.

1.How can i debug it from mobile? 
  Note: I already installed a chrome dev tools from my laptop, but the problem is that when the application launch in my mobile it doesn't use a browser. 
2. How can i call my sencha app in the chrome browser mobile.

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely yours,

Jhon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you mainly trying to access the same dev tools that the Chrome browser gives you? If so, there are a few solutions out there. For Android you can use weinre for remote debugging:
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

In fact, PhoneGap had a hosted instance of this online a while ago, last I remember (quite a while ago) it was down for a long time, but I just checked and it *appears* functional:
http://debug.phonegap.com/
It will probably run slower than your own weinre, but it saves you the trouble of dealing with setting up on your own server.

If you are working on iOS there is actually a rather nice way built-in to iOS/OSX. You need a machine with OSX on it, plug in your iOS device or run the iOS simulator, and then open Safari on your laptop/desktop. Safari has a develop menu, allowing you to open debugging tools (inspector, console, etc) for your remote devices.

Comment: By the way, there is now built-in debugging if you use Chrome on both devices (you must use Chrome mobile browser). You need to have your device connected via USB to your computer though. It operates very similar to iOS/Safari.